# Detecting if the Opera Browser is installed using MFC

Tags: mfc, registry, opera

I have written some code which reads the registry to find out which browsers are installed. It gets the browser name and path.

I know that it does not include **Microsoft Edge** yet. But my question concerns **Opera**. For some reason it is not listed.

The registry key is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet
```

My PC has the following listed:

[image: Installed Browsers]

So:

1. How do we find out if the Opera Browser is **installed**?
2. How do we find out what the **path** is to the Opera Browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\opera.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

You must also read `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet`

(see [How to Register an Internet Browser...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/start-menu-reg))

Comment: I was encountering issues with reading the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` counterparts with a non-elevated application. So for consistency I am now using the `App Path` key which is available no matter the executable elevation.

Comment: You can read the `HKLM` hive from an unelevated process just fine. Your implementation probably requests privileges it does not need, if it fails.